# How do I select an XML sub-tree based on its contents?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I want search a specific attribute in an XML tree, afterwards I want extract the part of the tree in which this attribute is contained.

Example:

```
<records>   
    <name>Rose</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</records>
<records>   
    <name>jon</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</records>
<records>   
    <name>Tom</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</records>
```

I want to search for "Rose" and get the entire `<records>` element and its children.

---

Thanks everyone, you are very fast.

I have another question if I have some more nodes and they aren´t records how can I search in all of them?

```
<records>   
    <name>Rose</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</records>
<cars>   
    <name>jon</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</cars>
<houses>   
    <name>Tom</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</houses>
```

This time I will search by date = 11-1-11.

Comment: Please specify get. I guess the date...

Comment: I guess this will be a XPath answer :)

Comment: Please don't add multiple questions. Create a new question, and reference this one.

Answer (score 4):

You're not selecting on an attribute but on an element. That's a difference. Anyway, here's the XPath expression you could use:

```
//records[name[text()='Rose']]
```

Can also be made shorter:

```
//records[name='Rose']
```

Or if you're wary of white space messing things up:

```
//records[name[normalize-space(text()) = 'Rose']]
```

Comment: Since this user is new to Nokogiri, you might include how to use XPath to find an element, i.e. `doc = Nokogiri.XML(IO.read('my.xml')); record = doc.at_xpath("//records[name='Rose']")`; also, since you showed one 'shorter', you might also include `//records[normalize-space(name)='Rose']`

Answer (score 2):

The XPath-based [answer by @G_H](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344724/405017) is what I would personally use. However, for completeness, here's how you might do this in Nokogiri using only the CSS selector syntax and a little more Ruby:

```
names = doc.css('name')
rose  = names.find{ |el| el.text == "Rose" }
rose_record = rose.parent
```

Or on a single line:

```
rec = doc.css('name').find{ |el| el.text=="Rose" }.parent
```

*For more info see the [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) documentation.*

**Edit**: Since you're new to Nokogiri, here's how you create a document to start querying:

```
require 'nokogiri' # gem install nokogiri 
doc = Nokogiri.XML(File.read('my.xml'))
```

Comment: +1. Better suited to question than my answer. I'm no Ruby nor Nokogiri expert, so I focused on the expression.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of Ruby or Nokogiri but tested next `xpath` expression in [xqilla](http://xqilla.sourceforge.net/HomePage) and seems to work.

```
//records[data(name) = "Rose"]
```

Output:

```
<records>   
    <name>Rose</name>
    <date>12-1-11</date>
</records>
```

Comment: That's an XPath 2 expression. I don't think Nokogiri supports this.